# order of onCreate() and onClick()

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have a `Button` in my `Activity` which, if not clicked within 5 seconds from creating the `Activity`, I want to crash the App. I tried the following but found out from logging that the `OnClickListener` code is executed after all other code in `onCreate(Bundle)` is run. So the boolean is always `false` when it is checked. How can I fix this?

```
private Boolean isClicked = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("0-isClicked", String.valueOf(isClicked));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_map);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myBTN);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            isClicked = true;
            Log.e("1-isClicked", String.valueOf(isClicked));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    Log.e("2-isClicked", String.valueOf(isClicked));

    //let app crashes after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) if user didn't take action
    if (!isClicked) {
        Log.e("3-isClicked", String.valueOf(isClicked));
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    throw null;
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }   
}
```

And this is what LogCat gives:

```
E/0-isClicked﹕ false
E/2-isClicked﹕ false
E/3-isClicked﹕ false
E/1-isClicked﹕ true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the other way around: you crash your app anyway if in the 5 seconds, the user didn't click.

To ease the pain you can use [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and do something those lines:

```
public void onCreate(){
  new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.e("isClicked", String.valueOf(isClicked));
     }

     public void onFinish() {
        if(!isClicked) throw null;
     }
  }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Timer` for setting a task to be executed 5 seconds later and in that task you can finish the activity. Create the timer on `onCreate()`

```
timer = new Timer(); // Keep the timer (of type Timer) as a member of the activity class so you can access it later
timer.scheduleTask(timerTaskInstance, 5000); // timerTaskInstance is an instance of TimerTask for which you should override the run() method
```

Now if the button is clicked before the timer times out just cancel the timer on the button's listener method:

```
timer.cancel();
```

More info about [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand when oncreate is runned. Your three first log statments is from onCreate and should be:

```
E/0-onCreate﹕ false
E/2-onCreate﹕ false
E/3-onCreate﹕ false
```

See http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-activity